# Rails 3.1 record object instantiating twice in Controller actions?

Tags: rails-3.1, identity-map

I have a controller that basically fetches a record and instantiates into an object.
When it runs, the object is instantiated twice with different object_ids.

e.g.

```
def index
    @users= Users.all
    puts @users.object_id
end
```

This prints two different ids on the terminal where rails is running (only in rails 3.1). In Rails 3 its only one id.  It also instantiated two different user objects to two queries to the DB or Resource.

I have no clue. I don't even know what to google for. I saw something about `ActiveRecord::IdentityMaps` but I don't understand what's wrong here.